# Windows not showing in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

since yesterday i'm stuck with the dual boot. I can't see Windows 8.1 in the menu. The problem started when I removed Ubuntu from the windows disk manager, so I reinstalled it for solving it. Now I have that error, tried to solve with boot repair without success (http://www.paste2.org/87V4MBXY)

Comment: Have a look on [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 2):

use "boot-repair disk" google it. It is live CD about 600mb. Mandatory condition is it should be connected with WiFi before repairing boot loader.It will automatically scan your all bootable drives and will give you instructions on the spot. A menu will come where mouse will not work. In that condition you have to use tab to move courser and space to select.

Comment: I tried using it from Ubuntu and it gave me no results. Now I'm downloading it for burn it on a cd and i'll tell you. Thanks for helping.

Comment: 'Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.' Boot-Repair report shows your issue. Fast start/hibernation is Windows 8 or 10 issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: Damn, it worked but now my '\Windows\system32\winload.exe' is damaged.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what caused your issue, not enough information. Remember that when removing Linux as a secondary OS which was installed AFTER Windows was installed removes also Bootloader. In order to fix your issue you need a Recoverable CD and issue the following commands: bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot

Comment: If you have ISO of windows 8.1 then by booting it from usb you can repair boot loader of it. Then again you can create dual booting with Boot repair disk. On the other hand if you have backup of windows 8.1 you can restore it and then create Dual boot with same procedure.